# enviar por POST cuando el id es variable

Tags: javascript, post

En una página he creado una tabla que al hacer click sobre alguna fila esta envía a otra página. En la otra página quiero recoger la información por POST y no por GET.

El problema es que cada fila tiene un ID diferente y no consecutivo por lo cual al intentar recoger el valor en la siguiente página, no tengo un id único.

Mi tabla está de esta forma:

```
<form name="formListado" action="../rep/detalleDir.php" method="POST">
  <table name="tableRoster" id="id_tableRoster">
    <thead id="encabezados">...</thead>

    <tbody>
      <?php foreach ($res_listado as $key => $value) { ?>
        <tr name="idmedico" id="<?php echo $value['id_unico']; ?>" onclick="enviar2(this.id)">
          <td align="center"> ... </td>            
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

Pensaba usar un script para enviar a la siguiente página pero no termino de armarlo.

```
function enviar2 (idorigen) {
            var idMed = idorigen;
            document.getElementsByName('idmedico').value = idMed;
            document.formListado.submit();
}
```

Y finalmente en la otra página no me sirve de nada tener un `$_POST["algo"]` por que nunca se qué número es el que va a llegar.

¿Alguna sugerencia de cómo puedo enviar estos datos?, como dije antes no puedo utilizar GET ya que son datos sensibles que no quisiera tener en la barra de navegación.

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Si tú tienes un `input` cuya `name` es `algo`, cada vez que envíes el formulario, obtendrás lo que hay escrito en ese input al hacer: `$valorPosteado=$_POST["algo"];`  O sea, el input se llamará siempre del mismo modo, lo que cambiará será el valor que escribas en él.

Comment: Hola Francisco! Bienvenido... Te sugiero terminar el [tour] del sitio y obtener tu primera medalla!

Comment: El estándar HTML no limita la cantidad de forms que pueda tener una página, así que la solución mas simple suele ser tener un form por cada fila y todos apuntan al mismo archivo que procesa los datos.
Esto puede complicarse si hay mas datos que quieras enviar y que con este enfoque se repetirían, en ese caso puedes poner un checkbox en cada fila y el form engloba toda la tabla, del lado del servidor recibirías el value del checkbox seleccionado (el cual puede ser el id que necesitas diferenciar del resto)
Hay mas datos (comunes al resto) que desees enviar junto al id de cada fila?

Comment: te estas engalletando con los id, que otros datos van aparte del id que sacas de la fila? que datos espera recibir el servidor?

Comment: No se entiende muy bien tu pregunta, que es lo que realmente quieres recibir en tu servidor, y porque lo haces por una etiqueta `tr` esto creo que no se puede y si me equivoco por favor alguien me explique, en dado caso tienes que usar un `input` dentro de un `td`

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Si lo único que vas a enviar está dentro del row pues arma un form por cada row (y lo ocultas con estilos).

```
<?php
$res_listado = array(
array(
    'id_unico'=>1,
    'nombre'=>'Juan Perex',
    'datovergonzoso'=>'le huelen los pies',
),
array(
    'id_unico'=>2,
    'nombre'=>'Arnaldo Biroya',
    'datovergonzoso'=>'ronca en Do mayor',
),
array(
    'id_unico'=>3,
    'nombre'=>'Emilio Fuentes',
    'datovergonzoso'=>'No sabe comer chicles',
),
array(
    'id_unico'=>4,
    'nombre'=>'Rodolfo Innuit',
    'datovergonzoso'=>'le da verguenza decirlo',
),
);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<title>datatablesvaloroculto</title>
<style>
.markrow{background:#fe0;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table name="tableRoster" id="id_tableRoster">
<thead id="encabezados">...</thead>
<tbody>
  <?php foreach ($res_listado as $key => $value) { ?>
    <tr onclick="enviar2(<?php echo $value['id_unico']; ?>)">
      <td align="center">
      <form name="formListado-fila-<?php echo $value['id_unico'];?>" action="detalleDir.php" method="POST" style="display:none;">
      <input name="idMedico" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $value['id_unico']; ?>" />
      </form>
       <?php echo $value['nombre'];?>
      </td>
      <td>
       <?php echo $value['datovergonzoso'];?>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
 </tbody>
</table>
</body>
<script>
  function enviar2(id) {
    elForm= document.getElementsByName('formListado-fila-'+id)[0];
    elForm.submit();
  }
</script>
</html>
```

el detalleDir.php recibe lo que le mandes en el form correspondiente al row clickeado (en este caso solo hay un input llamado "idMedico" ):

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

dará como resultado:

```
array(1) {
  ["idMedico"]=>
 string(1) "2"
```

}

si clickeas en la row 2

Si necesitas enviar mas datos propios de cada fila (row) los incluyes como inputs dentro del form.

**2.** Si en cambio los datos extra son comunes a todas las filas y se repetirían mucho, ahi lo que puedes hacer es crear el form por fuera de la tabla, agregar un campo oculto para el id y setearlo antes del submit:

```
<?php
$res_listado = array(
array(
    'id_unico'=>1,
    'nombre'=>'Juan Perex',
    'datovergonzoso'=>'le huelen los pies',
),
array(
    'id_unico'=>2,
    'nombre'=>'Arnaldo Biroya',
    'datovergonzoso'=>'ronca en Do mayor',
),
array(
    'id_unico'=>3,
    'nombre'=>'Emilio Fuentes',
    'datovergonzoso'=>'No sabe comer chicles',
),
array(
    'id_unico'=>4,
    'nombre'=>'Rodolfo Innuit',
    'datovergonzoso'=>'le da verguenza decirlo',
),
);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<title>datatablesvaloroculto</title>
<style>
.markrow{background:#fe0;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form name="formListado" action="detalleDir.php" method="POST">
<input name="idMedico" type="hidden" value="desconocido" />
<input name="unCampoGenerico" type="hidden" value="informacion oculta no tan oculta" />
<input name="otroCampoGenerico" type="hidden" value="otra informacion oculta no tan oculta" />
deja un comentario antes de clickar:
<input name="comentario" type="text" />
<table name="tableRoster" id="id_tableRoster">
<thead id="encabezados">...</thead>
<tbody>
  <?php foreach ($res_listado as $key => $value) { ?>
    <tr onclick="enviar2(<?php echo $value['id_unico']; ?>)">
      <td align="center">
       <?php echo $value['nombre'];?>
      </td>
      <td>
       <?php echo $value['datovergonzoso'];?>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
 </tbody>
</table>
      </form>
</body>
<script>
  function enviar2(id) {
    elInput= document.getElementsByName('idMedico')[0];
    elInput.value=id;
    elForm= document.getElementsByName('formListado')[0];
    elForm.submit();
  }
</script>
</html>
```

ejemplo de lo recibido con el segundo código:

```
array(4) {
  ["idMedico"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["unCampoGenerico"]=>
  string(32) "informacion oculta no tan oculta"
  ["otroCampoGenerico"]=>
  string(37) "otra informacion oculta no tan oculta"
  ["comentario"]=>
  string(18) "voy a clickar el 3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba quitando el "name al " y agrega un input hidden debajo del form.  y sigue utilizando tu mismo script para hacer el submit.

lo que estamos corrigiendo es que el  no tiene el atributo value que hace el envio por metodo POST, solo se aceptan para input, select y textarea.

Espero te ayude!

```html
<form name="formListado" action="../rep/detalleDir.php" method="POST">

  <input type="hidden" name="idmedico"/>
  
  <table name="tableRoster" id="id_tableRoster">
    <thead id="encabezados">...</thead>

    <tbody>
      <?php foreach ($res_listado as $key => $value) { ?>
        <tr id="<?php echo $value['id_unico']; ?>" onclick="enviar2(this.id)">
          <td align="center"> ... </td>            
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
     </tbody>
   </table>
</form>
```